# Find and Replace ALL GUIDS in a document

Tags: xml, guid

I'm working with a PowerShell script that imports XML files and updates another system with the data.  The imported XML file has a bunch of GUIDs that need to be replaced with new GUIDs.

Example of XML string:

```
<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="LAST_NAME" Required="FALSE" ID="{88861a2a-e1d0-45b5-99e8-42c06779666}" SourceID="{12e5f41a-8728-4f54-854b-62b7cd516ac3}" StaticName="LAST_NAME" Name="LAST_NAME" ColName="nvarchar7" RowOrdinal="0" />
```

Is there a simple *find and replace*  mixed with a GUID generator in PowerShell? I'm running PS 5.1 in VSCode.

Comment: The question is fairly generic: what language are you planning to use ?
You can use most languages today to parse XML (and access ID attributes), instead of raw string find and replace. Some languages like [c# come with GUID generators built-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=netframework-4.8) (otherwise you could implement your own)

Comment: Good point, using PowerShell to import the XML file. I will update the post.  thx!